# Create Child Record from List Button

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create a child record from a List button of a custom object that has a Master-Detail relationship with the Opportunity object.  Everything works, except I need to pull in the Opportunity ID to populate the Master-Detail field of the child object.  Is this something that I can do without the need for a controller?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity_Share__c" tabStyle="Opportunity_Share__c" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
      <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunity_Share__c}" var="shr">
            <apex:column headerValue="Shared Credit">
                <apex:inputField value="{!shr.Share_Credit__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Shared %">
                <apex:inputField value="{!shr.Share_Percentage__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Type of Sharing">
                <apex:inputField value="{!shr.Type_of_Sharing__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>      
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```